# Move db2 from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, database, windows, db2

I'm trying to move `db2 db` from `windows` to `linux` server. When I move data to `linux` db by this **command:**

```
db2move DBNAME load -lo REPLACE -u userID -p password > load_remote.txt
```

I had this **error:**

```
 SQLCODE:  -3126  -  SQLSTATE:
 SQL3126N  Remote client requires absolute path for files and directories.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the files located?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to use the 'load client' syntax (instead of just load) ?

See the details in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html).

The LOAD command requires that the files to be loaded are already on the Db2-target-server.

The LOAD CLIENT alternative allows the files to be on a remotely connected Db2-client (or on your Windows Db2-server if that is the source machine).

You can also just copy the IXF files to the Linux Db2-server, and open an SSH session to that Linux environment and run the LOAD command there.  Your choice.

As with the LOAD command, LOAD CLIENT operates on one file at a time (in your case, one file per table) unless using lobsinsepfiles option, or other special cases.

Comment: One more question to you: Can I use load client for multiple files, and tables? (in one statement insert data in multiple tables)